# HQL query does not work properly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I've some problems with an HQL query:

```
@Query("Select s from Sport s JOIN s.categories as c where s.sportId = :sportId and c.categoryId = :categoryId")
Iterable<Sport> findByCategoryIdAndSportId(@Param("sportId")Long sportId, @Param("categoryId")Long categoryId);
```

This query returns all categories (seems it ignore the second AND clause) but only the sport that matchs with sportId.

These are my classes that represents Sport and Category:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sports")
public class Sport  implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long sportId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sportId")
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Category> categories;

    @Column
    private String sportName;

    ....get and set
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Categories")
public class Category implements Serializable
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sportId", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Sport sportId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long categoryId;

    ..get and set
```

**EDIT**

Suppose that:

```
Sport:
  |sportId | SportName  
  |1       |Rugby      
  |2       |Basket       
  |3       |Tennis
```

And Categories:

```
  |categoryId | CategoryName | sportId|
  |1          |Italy         |1       |
  |2          |England       |2       | 
  |3          |USA           |1       |
  |1          |Spain         |2       |
```

I want to obtain with my query (suppose sportId=1 and categoryId=1):

```
| sportId | SportName | categoryId | CategoryName |
   1         Rugby       1             Italy
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result you want to get from the query? Do you want to have all Sports with the sportId and the association Category filtered, so that it only contains the categories which have the given categoryId?

Comment: I assume with all categories you mean the categories collection in the Sport class. You cannot reduce the content of this collection with a query.

Comment: I UPDATE my question with other details.

Comment: "seems like", but you dont seem to have checked the SQL invoked (in the LOG). Why not do that, then there is no supposition?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200985/jpql-query-how-to-filter-rows-on-a-relationship).

You can invert the query to get the categories that have some specific sport:

```
Select c from Categories c JOIN Sport s where c.categoryId = :categoryId and s.sportId = :sportId
```